# How to merge cells only the tfoot tag in export datatables excel

Tags: jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I want to merge cells which contain only the "Total" text in the `tfoot` tag.

This is the code [text](https://jsfiddle.net/tkjcruvb/1/)

This is the result of export to excel[image: excel1]

And this is the result that i want to achieve [image: excel2]

I also looked at @gopal question here [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73280956/how-to-merge-first-row-of-excel-in-datatables) ,, and he got the answer by adding manually `ranges.push( "A1:J1" );` . but thats not what i want to.

I tried to use `colspan="4"` in the html, but the result is look like this.

[image: result]

sorry for my bad explanation, any help would be appreciated. thanks